# Finding which values in an array are present at least x times

Tags: c

I have an array with randomly generated numbers in it, and I need to find and store the numbers that are present at least x times. (I can easily find x, that is not important. It will be a set amount). The array will have around 100-200 elements.

I know I will have to use a loop, but I'm not sure how to structure the body of it. I'm relatively new to C programming, so this may be fairly trivial. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First pick **one** programming language

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your own attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: [Here is my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691339/941531) for you task in C++.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Most important: There are two language tags and the solution will be very different for C++ and C. Further, information about size of array may influence the solution.

Comment: @Yuunia Just added [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691339/941531) another solution in `C` language (before it was just `C++`). Please put a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented two solutions, one in `C` and one in `C++`.

**First solution in C**:

It is simple:

1. Input array of numbers. Either it is inputed from console (when `input = 1`) or generated automatically by random generator (set constant `input = 0` in first lines of `main()`). Input/generation is done by first loop. If generated automatically/randomly then set constants `n` (number of elements) and `x` (minimal allowed count) at first lines of `main()` function.
2. Sort them in ascending order by built-in function `qsort`. I provided `compare()` function for `qsort` to compare in ascending order.
3. Iterate through sorted array. On the way compute number `c` of consecutive equal numbers. If `c >= x` then it means we have at least `x` of consecutive equal numbers, it means this number occured at least `x` times, hence we output such number as matching our criteria.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVRNc5swEL3zKzbupAM2acCukxjidHroIbdeO20OMohEM0iiQrR2E/92d1cYDGl7rmZA0n487b5dKauqi6xk6vFweCNUVjY5h9va5qXYvHu680YyoUnk1ZZZkYFQFjItK2a4/0OLHDeqtjCFmoUwFmwCePYAB/kwWMPUx9U0IMvNYLtJnZXhtjEKDW9R@wEuYkjIa@12EW7i1Nt7HoFJJpTfoV9ewkRN4AKstqwE1cgNN6ALOpY/clOHMNmSXgolZCMxwAYxrIZCqLyHEKpqLJmJAmKwT1xhRCyHwmjpctIlB2cEzBi2C4GXNSfrCB654oZZDoapXMs@6ZYKhbkuoxC2OC/CI8aa0jme/WnLZIXoLmZUJq9diLwFXEF8DfES4gX9cTeHFYY6B5RGEK@cSdQqYvzHcIOqFRqgeo5a5017lNzg4tpBOUsHhRuCee/OuaF5Sa5dmJgb6MZS9IU2SJGogbehJzBP8GArJEe6FwkedlxfJYhzXF8P1qsElt06jgYO8dA7Xg5cWloL8B1JXflpVAbZLvzJvaNWuUi3CUyCtDepM6bQ4jyH83wSwluF33agH0O4Cp8A9q7WJywqsx8FKbHyRTfYjzusnLAtJz@FfYJay64dFK/rviWmrpht50tWljrza/GL64JEAapVC/uRVNRSkkttdo5xLiu7a2NzeCQjNxAIGaU43YJKYTYTQ3JOjPWiESHEBvsqHgZkuM5@HpmTBZ7iMg/gHOaRC/Oesm6v3DHxNucQdj0vRCjuTGc3wu14x8JgIG0cBPyZ5P3Fyv/w3XunP2V49irFDveb6or4vdbG@vj2YOkHlIfdc3Y0c/f2dD1HHMeO4/W/SKbHSsHLS0vW2ZpmfFDih@AVmWSdwd0atuOajAlJsFW73m@5cWAY8KBUNAbh/qVbacxmWTogrDCc@ywYvbsRva6HwzKChfff3prf)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int compare(void const * sa, void const * sb) {
    int a = *(int*)sa, b = *(int*)sb;
    return a < b ? -1 : a == b ? 0 : 1;
}

int main() {
    // "n" - total number of integers, "x" - minimum count to find
    // "input" - if 1 then read from console input array, else if 0 generate random
    int const n = 50, x = 3, input = 1;
    // Example of input: n = 50, x = 3, a = 3 6 17 15 13 15 6 12 9 1 2 7 10 19 3 6 0 6 12 16 11 8 7 9 2 10 2 3 7 15 9 2 2 18 9 7 13 16 11 2 9 13 1 19 4 17 18 4 15 10 
    // and output for this example: 2: 6 times, 3: 3 times, 6: 4 times, 7: 4 times, 9: 5 times, 10: 3 times, 13: 3 times, 15: 4 times, 
    if (input) {
        printf("Input n and x: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &n, &x);
        printf("Input array: ");
    } else
        srand(0); // You may init this with some randomness
    int * a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n); // Allocate memory for empty array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (input)
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        else {
            a[i] = rand() % 20; // Init numbers with random, you may input your numbers
            printf("%d ", a[i]); // Print generated numbers
        }
    }
    if (!input)
        printf("\n");
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), compare);
    int c = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (i == n || a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
            if (c >= x)
                printf("%d: %d times, ", a[i - 1], c);
            c = 1;
        } else
            ++c;
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
50 3
3 6 17 15 13 15 6 12 9 1 2 7 10 19 3 6 0 6 12 16 11 8 7 9 2 10 2 3 7 15 9 2 2 18 9 7 13 16 11 2 9 13 1 19 4 17 18 4 15 10
```

---

**Second solution in C++**:

Use [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to count number of occurances of each number, by iterating (in a loop) over input array and incrementing by 1 count of current nummber inside map, then iterate (in a second loop) through this map and output those numbers that occur at least `x` times.

Also I used `std::map` specifically to have nice sorted output of numbers, if you don't need sorted order and need more speed then use [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of `std::map` exactly same way (also do `#include <unordered_map>` instead of `<map>`).

Full code is below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNa9wwEL37VzwcUrxsugkNvew6hpJLT@2h9BRCUOTZRGCPjD5apyW/fTuWvFmH6iIx897TezN6GD7qTvHT4XBmWHexJdTG@uBI9U1xqmkf2s48Lku/SAfrlpVeDU0RveEnsOrJD0oThLgrCsMBvTJcrfC3gBxv/tBDgLbsAxg3@Hy1w@UlvtrfAuQXcOwfyfn/waOArxP2S0BHSkrh2fjMCkb@zRynuK2uVgn501MGmT0sdy9oKZDrDRsfjMYEtb2HcgQmaqlNEjlhLd4bqIqz1LeFr711qGZzRmxJBIMaajPVKsGv1@YYeDrqztwLLDlb4RyfcuYftqfZw7vY09E2BtR1pspdokyc7zEM0rHRwfD0WhJfiyWVuO12qSILmtJczANtoDnkjije2shHGViZk9ZRTGlaZFUxWIxbqNWbwfVaRO7G@zed2dnsR8auQtaCOu6rHMvFpk7KecEfMGwnZ6c/ZGvVsPEk/RbNDcZTaxl02OyN8@lZbmVSqTSz0ujSnxeQESa@oxAdy9aK18PhHw)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    size_t const n = 50; // How many numbers
    size_t const x = 3; // At least this many times
    srand(0); // Use this if only deterministic randoms are needed
    vector<int> a(n); // Numbers
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        a[i] = rand() % 20; // Some random numbers
        cout << a[i] << " "; // Output our input numbers
    }
    cout << endl;
    map<int, size_t> cnt;
    // Count number of occurances
    for (auto x: a)
        ++cnt[x];
    // Output numbers that occur at least "x" times
    for (auto const & p: cnt)
        if (p.second >= x)
            cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << " times,  ";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 6 17 15 13 15 6 12 9 1 2 7 10 19 3 6 0 6 12 16 11 8 7 9 2 10 2 3 7 15 9 2 2 18 9 7 13 16 11 2 9 13 1 19 4 17 18 4 15 10 
2: 6 times,  3: 3 times,  6: 4 times,  7: 4 times,  9: 5 times,  10: 3 times,  13: 3 times,  15: 4 times,
```